# Assigning multiple prefabs to a script which only allows one to be added

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script where it puts an object (premade) onto a premade path using LeanTween which works fine.

The way this works is you can assign one object to the "path adder" (MoveController) that has the Moveable script attached to it.

However, I need to be able to add new prefabs made during runtime to the MoveController so they follow the path.

So how would I go about making instantiated objects attach to the MoveController during runtime.

Thank you.

Moveable script, also instantiates the prefabs

```
public class Moveable : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _speedMetersPerSecond = 25f;

    private Vector3? _destination;
    private Vector3 _startPosition;
    private float _totalLerpDuration;
    private float _elapsedLerpDuration;
    private Action _onCompleteCallback;
    public GameObject Electron;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
        var NextOnPath = Instantiate(Electron, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            NextOnPath.AddComponent<Moveable>();
        }

        if (_destination.HasValue == false)
            return;

        if (_elapsedLerpDuration >= _totalLerpDuration && _totalLerpDuration > 0)
            return;

        _elapsedLerpDuration += Time.deltaTime;
        float percent = (_elapsedLerpDuration / _totalLerpDuration);
        Debug.Log($"{percent} = {_elapsedLerpDuration} / {_totalLerpDuration}");

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_startPosition, _destination.Value, percent);
    }

    public void MoveTo(Vector3 destination, Action onComplete = null)
    {
        var distanceToNextWaypoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, destination);
        _totalLerpDuration = distanceToNextWaypoint / _speedMetersPerSecond;

        _startPosition = transform.position;
        _destination = destination;
        _elapsedLerpDuration = 0f;
        _onCompleteCallback = onComplete;
    }
}
```

MoveController script

```
using System.Linq;

public class MoverController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Moveable target;
    private List<Transform> _waypoints;
    private int _nextWaypointIndex;


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _waypoints = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().ToList();
        _waypoints.RemoveAt(0);
        MoveToNextWaypoint();
    }

  private void MoveToNextWaypoint()
    {
        var targetWaypointTransform = _waypoints[_nextWaypointIndex];
        target.MoveTo(targetWaypointTransform.position, MoveToNextWaypoint);
        target.transform.LookAt(_waypoints[_nextWaypointIndex].position);
        _nextWaypointIndex++;

if (_nextWaypointIndex >= _waypoints.Count)
            _nextWaypointIndex = 0;
        
    }
}
```

[image: Premade object MoveController typically uses]

[image: Where MoveController is attached and inspector]

Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

I understand this is quite a loaded question but I would greatly appreciate any help!

## Solution

```
Moveable:
public class Moveable : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _speedMetersPerSecond = 25f;
    public List<Moveable> moveables = new List<Moveable>();
    private Vector3? _destination;
    private Vector3 _startPosition;
    private float _totalLerpDuration;
    private float _elapsedLerpDuration;
    private Action _onCompleteCallback;
    public GameObject Electron;

   // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Moveable NextOnPath = Instantiate(Electron, transform.position, Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<Moveable>();
            moveables.Add(NextOnPath.GetComponent<Moveable>());
            MoverController.instance.targets.Add(NextOnPath.GetComponent<Moveable>());
        }
}
}
```

MoveController:

```
public List<Moveable> targets;
    [SerializeField] private Moveable target;
    private List<Transform> _waypoints;
    private int _nextWaypointIndex;
    public static MoverController instance;
private void MoveToNextWaypoint()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < targets.Count; i++)
        {
            var targetWaypointTransform = _waypoints[_nextWaypointIndex];
            targets[i].MoveTo(targetWaypointTransform.position, MoveToNextWaypoint);
            targets[i].transform.LookAt(_waypoints[_nextWaypointIndex].position);
            _nextWaypointIndex++;

            if (_nextWaypointIndex >= _waypoints.Count)
                _nextWaypointIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

Note: Only the changed parts are displayed in the solution

Comment: Well .. no .. if the class only allows for one single object there is no way to assign multiple ones without modifying the code accordingly....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you use an [Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) then you can add as many prefabs as you want. You will still need to set the code in the script to handle multiple prefabs.

Although, it sounds like you might not understand the basics for C# and Unity and you might like to take a class, read a tutorial or watch a Youtube video.

---

## Update

Because your question is so broad, I cannot just give you the code. That's something you should pay a coder for. But I will tell you the general ideas of what will need to be done.

1. In the Moveable class, you need to [track your var NextOnPath after instantiating](https://forum.unity.com/threads/save-instantiated-objects.709040/) them. A great way to do this (As long as you don't plan to convert anything to JSON) would be with a List<>.
   For example:

   ```
   List<Moveable> moveables = new List<Moveable>();

   void Update()
   {
       //Some code before - with instantiation
       //It is best to track items by the script that you will use since you can just use moveables[i].gameObject to access the gameObject and moveables[i].transform to access transform
       moveables.Add(NextOnPath.GetComponent<Moveable>());
       //Some code after
   }
   ```
2. You might save computing power by [adding the Moveable script to your Electron prefab](https://forum.unity.com/threads/adding-a-script-to-a-prefab.19843/) so you use:
   `Moveable nextOnPath = Instantiate(electron, transform.position, Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<Moveable>();`
3. Look up [Singleton](https://gamedevbeginner.com/singletons-in-unity-the-right-way/), you can use this to assign values to your MoverController class easily:

```
public static MoverController instance;
void Awake()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return;
    }

    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}
```

Then in the Moveable class simply add it to MoverController

```
//Requires changing the above code

    void Update()
    {
        //Some code before - with instantiation
        MoverController.instance.targets.Add(NextOnPath.GetComponent<Moveable>());
        //Some code after
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for being such a pain but I am getting a compilation error: _Assets\Moveable.cs(25,38): error CS1061: 'MoverController' does not contain a definition for 'targets' and no accessible extension method 'targets' accepting a first argument of type 'MoverController' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)_

Comment: These are the pieces of code I now have: [Moveable] (https://gyazo.com/b7eabd251cd6f18c00f144fbcc5a0ae6), [MoveController] (https://gyazo.com/834417140593f347f4b581a899052cb8)

Comment: I did try and fix this myself, I made Moveable from a serializedfield into a public variable and I also tried to change it to 'instance.target.Add' however both these changes, independently or together gave me a bunch of other errors. Thank you for all your help so far though

Comment: The compilation error is because you need to define public List<Moveable> targets in MoverController.

There are many steps needed to get to where you want to be. Just take them in stride and when you get to an issue, toss it into google, experiment, make mistakes and if you still can't solve it, make a new post.

Comment: Okay thank you that seems to have fixed it (I had to jig a few other things around as well to adapt the code). However there is one last thing that I have to ask you about. ?The prefabs are being spawned and are being added the waypoint controller in a transform (which I am very thankful for by the way). However, **how do I adapt the code so the newly instantiated prefabs follow the path around like the original object does.** I did a bit of research and found that it is probably just a matter of a foreach loop but I did try doing that and can't seem to get it right. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, you can use a for or foreach loop (for loops are more basic and easier to control so I recommend starting there until you understand them) Then, probably in your MoverController MoveToNextWaypoint you just run it for every Movable in targets. It may look similar to: `for(int i = 0; i < targets.Count;i++){//do something with targets[i] }`

Comment: Thank you so much mate it finally works after weeks of headscratching. Thank you.