# Assign multiple prefabs to a script which only allows originally object to be assigned, how to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script where it puts an object (premade) onto a premade path using LeanTween which works fine.

The way this works is you can assign one object to the "path adder" (MoveController) that has the Moveable script attached to it.

However, I need to be able to add new prefabs made during runtime to the MoveController so they follow the path.

So how would I go about making instantiated objects attach to the MoveController during runtime.

Thank you.

Moveable script, also instantiates the prefabs

```
public class Moveable : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _speedMetersPerSecond = 25f;

    private Vector3? _destination;
    private Vector3 _startPosition;
    private float _totalLerpDuration;
    private float _elapsedLerpDuration;
    private Action _onCompleteCallback;
    public GameObject Electron;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
        var NextOnPath = Instantiate(Electron, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            NextOnPath.AddComponent<Moveable>();
        }

        if (_destination.HasValue == false)
            return;

        if (_elapsedLerpDuration >= _totalLerpDuration && _totalLerpDuration > 0)
            return;

        _elapsedLerpDuration += Time.deltaTime;
        float percent = (_elapsedLerpDuration / _totalLerpDuration);
        Debug.Log($"{percent} = {_elapsedLerpDuration} / {_totalLerpDuration}");

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_startPosition, _destination.Value, percent);
    }

    public void MoveTo(Vector3 destination, Action onComplete = null)
    {
        var distanceToNextWaypoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, destination);
        _totalLerpDuration = distanceToNextWaypoint / _speedMetersPerSecond;

        _startPosition = transform.position;
        _destination = destination;
        _elapsedLerpDuration = 0f;
        _onCompleteCallback = onComplete;
    }
}
```

MoveController script:

```
using System.Linq;

public class MoverController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Moveable target;
    private List<Transform> _waypoints;
    private int _nextWaypointIndex;


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _waypoints = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().ToList();
        _waypoints.RemoveAt(0);
        MoveToNextWaypoint();
    }

  private void MoveToNextWaypoint()
    {
        var targetWaypointTransform = _waypoints[_nextWaypointIndex];
        target.MoveTo(targetWaypointTransform.position, MoveToNextWaypoint);
        target.transform.LookAt(_waypoints[_nextWaypointIndex].position);
        _nextWaypointIndex++;

if (_nextWaypointIndex >= _waypoints.Count)
            _nextWaypointIndex = 0;
        
    }
}
```

[[image: Moveable script]]
[[image: MoveController script]]
Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

I understand this is quite a loaded question but I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: You asked this only the other day. No need to ask again [Can I assign multiple assets to a script in Unity which only allows 1 asset to be assigned to it in the inspector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74908683/can-i-assign-multiple-assets-to-a-script-in-unity-which-only-allows-1-asset-to-b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to change `private Moveable target;` to `private List<Moveable> targets = new List<Moveable>();` This will make it possible to have several targets. Add a public method into MoverController: `public void RegisterTarget(Moveable targetToAdd) { targets.Add(targetToAdd)`.

Now, whenever a Moveable object is created, make it call the RegisterTarget method. So it should look something like `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MoverController").GetComponent<MoverController>().RegisterTarget(`put the new target here`)`.

You would finally need to change the MoveToNextWaypoint() method, just put foreach(Moveable target in targets) around all of the logic, and it will repeat the code for each target.

I hope this was clear enough, let me know if you need clarification (or if I misunderstood your question).

Comment: This solution would cause all objects to move towards the same waypoint. Are you sure that’s what the OP is after, or might they be after objects that follow the path independently of each other?

Comment: If OP confirms this to be the case, I could revise my answer to account for that.

Comment: I keep getting an error saying I can't convert a gameobject to a moveable. These screenshots should help explain:

Comment: Error message: https://gyazo.com/33d1cdf4f341e434328084cd85d80adc Moveable script: https://gyazo.com/d52a6af58f2d1c0db86e07104937c75a MoveController script: https://gyazo.com/1076aed9e910248a4484b12c1bb3f18a.

Comment: This post got closed for being a duplicate so feel free to answer on: Can I assign multiple assets to a script in Unity which only allows 1 asset to be assigned to it in the inspector? (they were similar before but i edited it now to make it the same)

Comment: Here's how to fix that: You are giving an object of type GameObject when it wants an Object of type Moveable (which is a component of GameObject). Go to Moveable line 24 and add .GetComponent<Moveable>() it will give you the Moveable component of the GameObject you gave it. So use: .RegisterTarget(NextOnPath.GetComponent<Moveable>())